# Open files based on Tab names?

Tags: excel, vba, filepath

For the Following Code What I'm trying to do is get excel to take data from a range in one workbook and drop it into another workbook that it finds in a given folder based on the tab name.

In a folder on my desk top I have 4 files "Master, Processor Alex, Processor Sue, Processor Bill".  Master.xlsm has 4 tabs:"Skip Me, Alex, Sue, Bill". I need the ranges in the code below transferred from the corresponding tabs for Alex et al to the workbook last page.

Unfortunately I for some reason can't step through using F8 becasue on my lap top it opens some kind of project side bar.  Its giving me an error and I'm new to VBA so I'm not understanding the error.  BUT THIS project is very important to me.

I took a piece of code that worked with out a loop and tried to rebuild it with a loop and the workbook opening from tab name received below.  I'm getting an error where here was none before.

```
Sub SheetLoop()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim SourceWB As Workbook
Set SourceWB = ThisWorkbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws In Worksheets
  If ws.Name <> "Skip Me" Then                  
    ws.Activate
    ws.Select
    Range("A2:M10").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Scott\Desktop\VBA Proj\" & ws.Name & ".xlsx")'<----  -???

    Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Select 'Selects last worksheet page

    'Selects destination looking for first blank cell in "B"
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    For Each Cel In ws.Columns(2).Cells
        If IsEmpty(Cell) = True Then Cell.Select: Exit For
    Next Cel    ' corrected Cell > Cel

    ActiveSheet.Paste               'Pastes selection       
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clears Clipboard for next copy action  
  End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: You would start with a very simple subroutine that loops thru the 'Sheets' collection. That will provide the Sheet.Name (i.e. activeworkbook.Sheets(i).name)  Then make that name part of your filename string and open the workbook. If you want to try it and update your question with the code, we can give some other pointers.

Comment: It is frowned upon to simply write code for others - SO is not a site where people develop solutions for others. It is for helping people with specific issues they encounter (i.e. an error in their code). I see you had posted another question that had vba code included, so a simple subroutine is where you would start. Create a loop that will give all the sheet names, then add a line of code that created the path and file name (i.e. MSgBox "C:\...\xxx\" & <sheet Name> & ".xlsx".  Post that in your question and everyone will be glad to help with the minor cleanup.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to come up with some code of your own. We can help you fix it if it's broken but we're not here to write your code for you.

Simple code to iterate through sheets in a book is:

```
dim wkb as excel.workbook
dim wks as excel.worksheet
set wkb = thisworkbook ' or activework or whatever
for each wks in wkb.sheets ' iterate through the sheets
    msgbox "Now on sheet " & wks.name
next
```

Simple code to generate a workbook path from a sheet name, assuming wkb and wks have been defined, the new workbook is in the same folder as the book with your code, and the sheet name for wks is the name of the book to open, is:

```
dim mypath as string, newname as string, extn as string
extn = ".xlsx" ' or ".xls" or whatever
mypath = wkb.path
if not right(mypath,1) = "\" then mypath = mypath & "\"
newname = mypath & wks.name & extn
```

simple code to open a workbook, assuming you know the name is:

```
dim wkbdata as excel.workbook
set wkbdata = workbooks.open(newname)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not fully clear to me what you would like to do. But here's a piece of code that would open the files for you. You can use this to create the filenames and use them however you want.

```
For i = 1 to ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Workbooks.Open "C:\FilePath\" & Worksheets(i).Name & ".xlsx"

Next i
```

I hope this helps. If you post parts of your code or explain things in more detail, people here could assist you better.

Comment: Good idea. That should help

Comment: Scott, please! You are jumping around adding comments in two different places, so that makes it difficult to follow what you are talking about. I'm willing to help you, but you need to help also. Please answer the following: (1) What is 'system won't let me' mean? What are you trying to do? (2) What is "found the cel issue. Did i not do that?" does that mean you found the place in your code that I pointed out? If so, why not update your code? (3) Did you try to open a new question with the text you now have in your question? This post is pretty much dead. I'll clean up your code now.

Answer (score 0):

I have something really close included in code above.  I started from scratch using a basic loop that I tested in workbook then started dropping in elements of my old version.  then it broke.

Comment: When you run the above code, I assume you get a message box for each sheet? If so, then next step is to build the path  and open the file. I prefer to build a string with the name, then open Excel using that string.  So, either adapt what Sepehr Moravej posted, or what Winterknell posted. Put it INSIDE your loop.  And a suggestion... don't use any word when programming that can be confused with a reserved word (i.e. Current)  ... it may save you some head-scratching later on.

Comment: Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Scott\Desktop\VBA Proj\Processor " & ws.Name & ".xlsx")  multiple stabs gives error 1004.

Comment: There is ZERO chance you are running the code you show in your question, so we don't know what you are actually trying to execute. Your 'For Each Cel' is not matched with 'Next cell'. As I said before, if you build a string with the full path & name, it is easy and smart to display it before trying to open the workbook. Just use 'Debug.Print <your string>'  or 'MsgBox <your string>' Did you post the Open in your prior comment because that was where you got the error? If not, it is misleading people.

Comment: found the cel issue.  Did i not do that?

Answer (score 0):

By "system wont let me step through" I mean hardly and of the VBA hot keys like F8 work.  It opens some other windows 10 function.

I'm posting the below more as a contribution for others who may need it. It works,  thanks go to Tonyyy on MrExcel forums.  I disabled it line by line to work on the next section so I may have an errant "'" somewhere. I think I got them all.

```
Sub UpdatebyLoop_2()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim SourceWB As Workbook, destinationWB As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet


                 'Data Transfer Section
Set SourceWB = ThisWorkbook
On Error GoTo errHandler
For Each ws In SourceWB.Worksheets
 If ws.Name <> "Skip me" And ws.Name <> "Skip me also" Then
     Set destinationWB = Workbooks.Open(SourceWB.Path & "\" & ws.Name  & ".xlsx")
    ws.Range("B6:AK30").Copy Destination:=destinationWB.Sheets (Sheets.Count). _
        Cells(destinationWB.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End( xlUp).Row + 1, 2)
          destinationWB.Close savechanges:=True

   End If
 'Repeat on next worksheet
Next ws
With Application
    .CutCopyMode = False
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
Exit Sub

errHandler:
    'MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
    "Sorry, it seems the worksheet name - " & ws.Name & " - does not match a workbook name."
   Resume Next
```

End Sub